# best file to use for configuration with a multiline support

Tags: java, properties

I am having a java program which is configurable by .properties file.

But one of the config key , I need a multi line value.

For eg:

```
#proerties file start
key1=value1
desc=a long long line /
next line/
and again next line with a very long desc
/(need to give some new line)
/
something else
from path D://myfile.txt
```

Now as you can see this is very tiresome and user needs to be educated about escaping.

So I want to know is there any better and elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes java properties must escape multiline text as:

```
# The following is a multi-line description.
desc=Mi ne scias,\
    chu chi tio funkcias, chu ne.\
    Chu vi havas ideon?
```

Furthermore special characters may need to be u-escaped.

But there are some properties editors around. Too many to just name one. Search for one with multiline capabilities, u-escaping special characters, handling comments, and maybe providing good i18n support (different languages side-by-side).

Comment: I prefer the properties editor in the NetBeans IDE, with either Open or Edit. In one case you get side by side editing. You can add a locale (language). With others I would not have much experience without trying them out. Sorry.